# how to access array created in another function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* arr_test(int);

int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;

int *new_arr;

new_arr=arr_test(n);

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  new_arr[i]++;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  cout<<"new array "<< new_arr[i]<<endl;

return 0;
}

int* arr_test(int n)
{
int arr[n];

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  cin>>arr[i];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  cout<<"old array "<< arr[i]<<endl;

return arr;
}
```

output:

> 2
>   20
>   10
>   old array 20
>   old array 10
>   Segmentation fault

I know why i'm getting segmentation fault because i'm accessing the memory which is not there i mean the array which has scope only on arr_test function. But I want to get that array. I tried "static" but it's saying arr[n] is not constant. I can make it global but I size of 'n' must get from user. How can I access that array?. If you have another method to get it please post it but remember the constraint arr size must be user given and array must be in arr_test function. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: In C++ you should prefer the `std::vector` or `std::array` wrapper over raw C style array. C arrays are bad, they don't know their size and are prone to _shape-shifting_ to pointers.

Comment: `int arr[n];` is not standard C++ - and returning the address of a stack allocated variable is always bad

Answer (score 1):

You return an array `int arr[n];` which is destroyed after leaving scope of the function.

Try to return array allocated in memory:

```
int* arr_test(int n)
{
    int* arr = new int[n];

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arr[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<"old array "<< arr[i]<<endl;

    return arr;
}
```

But after than you need to delete allocated memory by `delete [] new_arr;`

Also you can use array reference to use array from automatic memory:

```
void arr_test2(int arrByReference[], int n)
{
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>arrByReference[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<"old array "<< arrByReference[i]<<endl;
}

//...
int array[n];
arr_test2(array,n);
```

In this case you don't need to delete memory. It will be deleted when `array` will leave scope

Comment: Works (just like my solution would). Just make sure the caller frees the allocated memory when the array is not used anymore.

Comment: @RobertKock thanks. I have added this info and another example for arrays from automatic memory.

Answer (score 1):

Within your function `arr_test` the local variable `arr[n]` is placed on the stack but used as the return value.
When the function returns, the stack is cleared.
If you want to use a local variable as a return value, you should make sure it's not cleared when the function returns.
This can be obtained by declaring the local variable as `static int arr[n];`.

Comment: OP stated they tried that and it didn't compile (rightfully so)

Comment: I missed the fact the `n` was passed as a parameter. Of course it won't compile in that case. I guess the answer Alex Usachov gave is better.

Answer (score 0):

In idiomatic C++, a dynamic array of `int` is pronounced `std::vector<int>`, not `int[]`. `using namespace std;` introduces *many* names into global scope, and is a recipe for subtle bugs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> arr_test(int);

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    auto new_arr = arr_test(n);

    std::for_each(new_arr.begin(), new_arr.end(), [](int & val){ ++val; });

    std::for_each(new_arr.begin(), new_arr.end(), [](int val){ std::cout << "New array" << val << std::endl; });

    return 0;
}

std::vector<int> arr_test(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> arr(n);

    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), n, new_arr.begin());

    std::for_each(new_arr.begin(), new_arr.end(), [](int val){ std::cout << "Old array" << val << std::endl; });

    return arr;
}
```